# What is the difference between serializable and repeatable read isolation level?

Tags: sql, database

What is the difference between serializable and repeatable read isolation level? Can anyone please give a simple example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Dirty_reads
Neither serializable nor repeatable read allows dirty reads. Repeatable read allows phantom rows, while serializable doesn't.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Summary:

In a Repeatable Read isolation level, new rows can be inserted into the dataset.

In a Serializable isolation level, all the rows are locked for the duration of the transaction, no insert, update or delete is allowed.

Please refer to these for examples and explanations.

<sup>*Original links are broken — Wayback Machine links are from the same day and time.*</sup>

**Isolation Level — serializable**

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10467/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-serializable.aspx

Wayback Machine [SQL Server Transaction Level Serializable](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907175058/http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10467/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-serializable.aspx)

**Isolation Level — repeatable-read**

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10466/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-repeatable-read.aspx

Wayback Machine [SQL Server Transaction Level Repeatable Read](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907184829/http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10466/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-repeatable-read.aspx)

Comment: It might be good to give a more nuanced discussion — I believe that part of the distinction is that the current transaction can insert, delete and update rows, but other transactions are constrained from making some changes until the current transaction commits.

Answer (score 15):

**Repeatable read** prevents only non-repeatable read (so you can read the same data in the same transaction without fear of someone changing it - even though it's a rare need for doing it).

**Serializable** prevents both non-repeatable read and phantom rows (so you can't even INSERT data). That means you can READ and WRITE (SELECT, UPDATE) rows that are not included with serializable transaction, but you can't DELETE OR INSERT rows on TABLE level.

Both repeatable read and serializable are very strict and there is not always need for them!

Comment: With the serializable isolation level you still can insert and delete data into/from the table as long as it doesn't meet the SELECT criteria.

Answer (score 1):

besides above , different implement is differed.

such as mysql , the repeatable read will not cause phantom problem.
as [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#:%7E:text=SERIALIZABLE%20enforces%20even%20stricter%20rules,issues%20with%20concurrency%20and%20deadlocks)

> SERIALIZABLE enforces even stricter rules than REPEATABLE READ, and is used mainly in specialized situations, such as with XA transactions and for troubleshooting issues with concurrency and deadlocks.