# DBMS - COMMIT BEFORE SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have 2 terminals in both of them i set autocommit= 0 in the first terminal i insert 5 rows and then i type commit it supposed now in the second terminal i can see the updates right? but this is not true i need to type commit in the second terminal before i type 'select * from table' why this is necessary can someone explain me?

Comment: `commit` command commits data for the session, two terminals - two different sessions, you have to commit in first terminal first to see updated data in second terminal

Comment: yes but in the first terminal i insert a couple of rows and then i pressed commit , it supposed in the second terminal to be able to see the previous changes..but to works i've made commit before i try to view the updated inforamtion

Comment: I cannot understand how you can "press commit" in terminal, you have to "type" commit to actually apply changes

Comment: this is very strange

Comment: "type commit" you didnt get me

Comment: what do you think `commit` does?

Comment: i have 2 terminals in both of them i set autocommit= 0 in the first terminal i insert 5 rows and then i type commit it supposed now in the second terminal i can see the updates right? but this is not true i need to type commit in the second terminal before i type 'select * from table'

Comment: ah, I suggest you to fix wording in question then, as question `in the first terminal i insert a couple of rows and i've pressed commit in the second window` which means that you haven't executed commit in first terminal

Comment: what database, what terminal software?

Comment: mysql database ubuntu terminal

Comment: you cannot send sql queries via ubuntu terminal, probably you're using mysql cli utils?

Comment: of curse..............

Comment: it is not of course, there millions of mysql clients, which can have their own bugs/features/caches

Comment: also it looks like your case https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53211

Comment: and this one looks like answer http://ilmarkerm.blogspot.com/2012/06/little-side-effect-of-having-autocommit.html

Comment: dam... didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

it looks weird, but according to [mysql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53211) and [blog entry](http://ilmarkerm.blogspot.com/2012/06/little-side-effect-of-having-autocommit.html) it is expected behavior with `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level, change level to `READ COMMITTED` to avoid this problem

```
set session transaction isolation level read committed;
```

Comment: didn't work.. same as before i need to make commit before i see the updated information

Comment: @Costas.K have you executed this statement in both terminals?

Comment: dam it worked !! you goddamn righ, butt what exactly is the isolation level read?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034976/difference-between-read-commit-and-repeatable-read -->  ok thnk you very much