# Difference between ReadCommitted and Repeatable Read isolation level in Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

These days I improved my knowledge about Isolation Level of transactions.

In particular, i had problem to understand well the difference between Read Committed and Repeatable Read.

[I've read this fantastic article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034976/difference-between-read-commit-and-repeatable-read), and I understand all about dirty-reads, non-repeatable read and phantoms read  but i don't understand what happen with multiple transactions in update.

Example: 
Table: "Test"   (Field: ID_REC - Data) 
Transaction A:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed;
begin transaction

update test
set DATA = 't1'
where ID_REC = 1

waitfor delay '00:00:20'
commit transaction
```

Transaction B: (the same but with another record)

```
set transaction isolation level read committed;
begin transaction

update test
set DATA = 't2'
where ID_REC = 2

commit transaction
```

I execute both transactions in two seconds.
Second transaction doesn't start until first one is finished. 
And also i can't execute query (select * from test).

So:  why happen this? Transactions works on different rows... and about this case, what is the difference between Read Committed and Repeatable Read?