# Why can not update a row that already updated by another transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, isolation-level

I am trying to understand the repeatable read isolation level of MySQL InnoDB. But it has a behavior that I cannot understand when I tried these 2 transactions.

Here is my initialization for the test

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `test`;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                          |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `test`;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;
+-----------------+
| @@TX_ISOLATION  |
+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

| No | Tx1 | Tx2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | START TRANSACTION | START TRANSACTION |
| 2 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 1 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 1 |
| 3 | SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE ID = 1 FOR UPDATE;# return 1 |  |
| 4 | UPDATE `test` SET ID = 2 WHERE ID = 1; # OK | UPDATE `test` SET ID = 3 WHERE ID = 1; # Lock wait |
| 5 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 2 | # Keep waiting |
| 6 | COMMIT; # OK | # Query OK: rows matched:0, changed: 0, warnings: 0 |
| 7 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 2 | SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE ID = 1;# Return 1 |
| 8 |  | UPDATE `test` SET ID = 3 WHERE ID = 1; #Query OK: rows matched:0, changed: 0, warnings: 0 |
| 9 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 2 | SELECT * FROM `test`;# Return 1 <-- cannot update 1 to 3 even the row exists |
| 10 |  | UPDATE `test` SET ID = 3 WHERE ID = 2;#Query OK: rows matched:1, changed: 1, warnings: 0 |
| 11 |  | COMMIT; #OK |
| 12 | SELECT * FROM `test`# Return 3 | SELECT * FROM `test`# Return 3 |

I wonder how MySQL treats ID=1 and ID=2 in Tx2 at lines 8 and 10.
And If I use `UPDATE test SET ID = 3 WHERE ID = 2` at line 4 of Tx2, lock wait is still required even Tx1 only hold the exclusive lock for ID = 1?

Comment: The lock wait when the ID is different is probably waiting on a gap lock.

Answer (score 2):

At step 8, there is no longe a locked record, because `TX1` has done a COMMIT, and this clears the lock.

There is also no longer a record with ID=1, because it has been updated.

At step 9 and 10, It is not possible for `Tx2` to update the record, because of REPEATABLE READ.  It cannot *see* the record with id=2, and also no longer find the record with id=1 (because it is gone/changed).

Only after a COMMIT, `Tx2` can see the new/changed data.

Comment: But ID=1 still visible with Tx2 via select. It's so weird if we can select it but cannot update it. Update an ID that not visible is also weird too.

Comment: It is still visible because of REPEATABLE READ, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034976/difference-between-read-commited-and-repeatable-read#:~:text=Repeatable%20read%20is%20a%20higher,unchanged%2C%20and%20available%20to%20read.) great explanation why this data cannot be changed.  (NOTE: The read data cannot be changed, but the data in your database can !)